# Prestashop Nginx + Advanced Search 4 module + rewrite rules

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, prestashop

Could someone help me with  rewrite rules for Advanced Search 4 prestashop module?

Basic htaccess rules are:

```
RewriteRule ^as4_seositemap.xml$ modules/pm_advancedsearch4/sitemap/seositemap.xml [L]
RewriteRule ^as4_seositemap-([0-9]+).xml$ modules/pm_advancedsearch4/sitemap/seositemap-$1.xml [L]
```

it's ok, i've made :

```
 location = /as4_seositemap.xml {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /modules/pm_advancedsearch4/sitemap/seositemap.xml break;
    }

    location /as4_seositemap {
        rewrite ^/as4_seositemap-([0-9]+).xml$ /modules/pm_advancedsearch4/sitemap/seositemap-$1.xml break;
    }
```

but stack with this part :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^controller=products-comparison [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})?/?s/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*) index.php?fc=module&module=pm_advancedsearch4&controller=advancedsearch4&isolang=$1&id_seo=$2&seo_url=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^isolang=([a-z]{2})&id_seo=([0-9]+)&seo_url=([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*).*p=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^advancedsearch4.php /%1/s/%2/%3?p=%4 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^isolang=([a-z]{2})&id_seo=([0-9]+)&seo_url=([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*)
RewriteRule ^advancedsearch4.php /%1/s/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_seo=([0-9]+)&seo_url=([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*).*p=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^advancedsearch4.php /s/%1/%2?p=%3 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_seo=([0-9]+)&seo_url=([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*)
RewriteRule ^advancedsearch4.php /s/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Tryed to do something like this with http://winginx.com/ru/htaccess :

```
location ~* ^/([a-z])/?/([0-9])/([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*)$ {
    rewrite "^/([a-z]{2})?/?s/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*)" /index.php?fc=module&module=pm_advancedsearch4&controller=advancedsearch4&isolang=$1&id_seo=$2&seo_url=$3 break;

}

if ($query_string ~ "^isolang=([a-z]{2})&id_seo=([0-9]+)&seo_url=([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*).*p=([0-9]+)$"){
    rewrite ^/advancedsearch4.php /%1/%2/%3?p=%4 redirect;
}

if ($query_string ~ "^isolang=([a-z]{2})&id_seo=([0-9]+)&seo_url=([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*)"){
    rewrite ^/advancedsearch4.php /%1/%2/%3? redirect;
}

if ($query_string ~ "^id_seo=([0-9]+)&seo_url=([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*).*p=([0-9]+)$"){
    rewrite ^/advancedsearch4.php /%1/%2?p=%3 redirect;
}

if ($query_string ~ "^id_seo=([0-9]+)&seo_url=([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*)"){
    rewrite ^/advancedsearch4.php /%1/%2? redirect;
}
}
```

but all i've got is 404 for seo url.
Please tell what i do wrong? I read few books about nginx rewrite but can't understand clearly how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The first location solved and works.

```
rewrite "^/([a-z]{2})?/?s/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*)" /index.php?fc=module&module=pm_advancedsearch4&controller=advancedsearch4&isolang=$1&id_seo=$2&seo_url=$3 break;
```

but still dont know what to do with others..